# Upload files to a mediawiki via PHP

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm currently using [Extension:Push](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPush) to copy articles from one MediaWiki (1.16) installation (which sits in local intranet and is not accessible from the outside) to another one. However, Push can only copy files by having the remote MediaWiki download the file, which isn't possible in this case (the intranet wiki isn't accessible from the outside for a reason).

So, I need some way to bind to the Upload API of MediaWiki directly. My current attempt is the following:

```
$header = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$multipart_boundary.'\r\n'.
          'Cookie: '.$cookies;
$file_contents = file_get_contents ($imagePage->getDisplayedFile()->getFullUrl());
$content = "--".$multipart_boundary.'\r\n'.
           'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'.basename($imagePage->getDisplayedFile()->getFullUrl()).'"\r\n'.
           'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n'.
           $file_contents.'\r\n'.
           '--'.$multipart_boundary.'\r\n'.
           'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"\r\n\r\n'.
           'upload\r\n'.
           '--'.$multipart_boundary.'\r\n'.
           'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format"\r\n\r\n'.
           'json\r\n'.
           '--'.$multipart_boundary.'\r\n'.
           'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ignorewarnings"\r\n\r\n'.
           '1\r\n'.
           '--'.$multipart_boundary.'\r\n'.
           'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"\r\n\r\n'.
           $token.'\r\n';

$context = stream_context_create (array (
  'http' => array (
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => $header,
    'content' => $content,
    ),  
  )); 

$response = file_get_contents ($target, false, $context);
```

I don't get any error message (neither from local nor remote Apache), but the file isn't appearing, either. Anyone got an idea what's wrong, has a working solution or can at least point me to the involved mediawiki functions so I can put some debug logging in them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the original author updated the extension. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet, but if you're creating pages on the remote Wiki (whose URL you know) then it looks as if the way to do it is described in [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aEdit) which says that you need to get an edit token and then post with the token, your page contents, etc.  You get XML-formatted messages back to track success or failure.